# Vuejs router 3.0.1 path issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I've just come across a strange issue and I'm not sure how to resolve it.
Here's a sample of some route config:

```
routes: [
  {
    path: '/signin',
    name: 'signin',
    component: SignIn
  },
  {
    path: '/message/:messageType',
    name: 'message',
    component: Message,
    props: true
  }
]
```

Navigating to the various routes works perfectly, however the problem comes in when I'm on the Message component and try to navigate to any other route. My url would look like this:

> https://localhost:8080/message/somemessage

When I click the Sign In link, I get this path:

> https://localhost:8080/message/signin

instead of

> https://localhost:8080/signin

I'm using the regular router-link:

```
<router-link to="signin">Sign In</router-link>
```

I get that it's matching on the closest route, but this is a problem for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the documentation for named routes: [Vue Router, named routes](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/named-routes.html).  I think you need to write your link this way:

```html
<router-link :to="{ name: 'NAME_OF_ROUTE', params: { userId: 123 }}">User</router-link>
```

In other words, I think you need to give the `to` attribute an object with a `name` property.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of [Api/router-link](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link), the `to` attribute is relative path as referred to root:

> The target location is specified with the `to` prop. It renders as an
>   `<a>` tag with correct `href` by default

So, if you want to use `router-link` element without passing an object, I think you have to use what you set as `path`, and not `name` property:

```
<router-link to="/signin">Sign In</router-link>
```